# How to run a method when onPublish is triggered in Adobe Media Server?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, rtmp, adobe-media-server

I have the following code inside Adobe Media Server's `main.asc` (latest version, 5.0.10 I think):

```
application.onPublish = function (clientObj, streamObj) {
  for (var i = 0; i < application.clients.length; i++){
    application.clients[i].call("streamConnected");
  }
}
```

And this code inside my ActionScript (3.0) file, connected to my flash file:

```
nc = new NetConnection();

nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onConnectionStatus);
nc.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, asyncErrorHandler);
nc.client = { onBWDone: function():void{}, streamConnected: function():void{} };
nc.connect(videoURL);

...

public function streamConnected(...rest):void {
  trace("Stream Connected");
}
```

I'm not too sure what my code means - most of it has been sourced from various sections of the Internet, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've defined your `streamConnected()` function twice, so remove one of its definitions like for example : `nc.client = { onBWDone: function():void{}, streamConnected: streamConnected };` ...

Comment: @akmozo Thank you so much for that - the documentation for Adobe Media Server (and ActionScript in general) is so sparse. If you could make that into an answer, I would accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your current code, the only function that will be executed is the empty one which is defined inside the `nc.client` object because the `streamConnected()` function is not attached to the `nc.client`'s `streamConnected` property.

So, to get the `"Stream Connected"` message, you can change that anonymous function like this for example :

```
nc.client = { 
    onBWDone: function():void{}, 
    streamConnected: function(...rest):void {
        trace("Stream Connected");
    }
};
```

or simply you can use your existing `streamConnected()` function :

```
nc.client = { 
    onBWDone: function():void{}, 
    streamConnected: streamConnected
};
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: yep, thank you for that - definitely helped me out more than it probably seems.